Flyback diode with 12 V/4 A water pump
I have a DC water pump (12 V/4 A) and I used a 1N4001 flyback diode connected with it in parallel. The 1N4001 only can handle max. 1 A constant current and 30 A transient.
Should I use a diode to handle a bigger constant current in this case? I am not switching on/off the water pump that frequently. Which diode model can I choose?

If you want peace of mind and reliability use a pennies-more-expensive better part.

The peak current will not exceed the maximum current. It's possible that if you were to just flick the current on and off before the pump got going it might be more than 4A briefly but generally it will be equal to the pump run current and drop rapidly.
I would probably use a 1N5404 or 1N5406 3A diode, which is a very robust cheap jellybean through-hole part.

Be careful. The pump takes 4 A to run. It will take much more to start. Check the pump data. It could be 24 A peak. What if the power is turned off at the peak start current? So it is the peak current that decides the diode, not the average current. Without seeing pump data then play safe with a 3 A diode. If you are making lots of these then get pump data by measurement or internet and you might be able to get away with your proposed 1 A diode. Remember that diodes can fail short circuit and that would sure stop the pump.
